# How to get text from the image?

Tags: ocr

I have tried a lot of online OCR services, but no one of them produced correct list of nicknames on the screen.

Are there any ways how to get correct nicknames from the screen?
[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBN0e.jpg)

Comment: https://www.onlineocr.net/

Comment: This is a programming site, not a "use things on the internet" site, so you'll need to have some code you're having trouble with for this to be on topic. There's hundreds of OCR libraries for various programming languages, so you're not pinned to a particular web service.

Comment: Actually I have tried "pytesseract" in Python, but it didn't give the correct result.